# Замена темы в приложении

Tags: themes, android

Здравствуйте!

Я хотел поменять тему, что в последствии и сделал, но немного не таким образом, как предполагал. В итоге остался вопрос, почему у меня не меняется тема так, как она должна меняться?

Вот варианты, которые я пробовал применить, для того чтобы поменять тему в программе:

Вариант 1. "Вставляем ручками". Открываем файл - Manifest.
И в данном случае вместо "`AppTheme`" в этой строке "`android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >`" вставляем другую тему. Например: "`Theme.NoTitleBar.FullScreen`". Это будет выглядеть так:   `android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitleBar.FullScreen"`.

Вот код оригинала :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.progect20"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
 android:minSdkVersion="8"
 android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

 <application
 android:allowBackup="true"
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
 <activity
 android:name=".MainActivity"
 android:label="@string/app_name" >
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Меняем строку:

Вариант 1.1

```
"android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitleBar.FullScreen"
```

> выдает ошибку -
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Typeerror:
> Error: No resource found that matches
> the given name (at 'theme' with value
> '[[[[[@style](/users/10804/styles)](/users/10804/styles)](/users/10804/styles)](/users/10804/styles)](/users/10804/styles)/Theme.NoTitleBar.FullScreen').    AndroidManifest.xml /Progect20  line
> 11    Android AAPT Problem

Вариант 1.2

```
"android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.FullScreen
```

выдает ошибку -

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Typeerror:
> Error: No resource found that matches
> the given name (at 'theme' with value
> '[[@android](/users/8445/android)](/users/8445/android):style/Theme.NoTitleBar.FullScreen').    AndroidManifest.xml /Progect20  line
> 11    Android AAPT Problem

Как я понял, ошибка связанна с тем, что компилятор не находит в ресурсах данную тему.

Или можно сделать то же самое, но только с помощь таблицы, в дальнейшем избежав ошибок:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3uqbcxKb0o

После того как я якобы установил новую тему, пробую ее запускать на эмуляторе, и при запуске программы она вылетает с ошибкой "приложение остановлено".

А вот лог Errors "виртуальной машины" в Eclipse:

```
 09-03 13:03:39.245: E/Trace(786):
 error opening trace file: No such file
 or directory (2) 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): FATAL
 EXCEPTION: main 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786):
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
 start activity
 ComponentInfo{com.example.progect20/com.example.progect20.MainActivity}:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: You
 need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme
 (or descendant) with this activity.
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
 Method) 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
 Method) 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): Caused by:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: You
 need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme
 (or descendant) with this activity.
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:110)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:99)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 com.example.progect20.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
 09-03 13:03:39.595:
 E/AndroidRuntime(786): ... 11 more
```

Судя по логу, тут нам говорят, что нужно использовать темы, связанные с AppCompat ну или наследовать от AppCompat-компонента подобные темы.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Так вот, почему у меня выскакивает эта ошибка? Почему именно с взаимодействием AppCompat я должен использовать темы? Почему нельзя их просто поставить стандартным образом?

Спасибо.

Comment: Если вы хотите использовать ActionBar из support library v7, то с ней нужно ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО использовать предлагаемую тему.

Comment: если активити наслудается от  ActionBarActivity, то тема для этой активити должна быть наследником Theme.AppCompat

Answer (score 1):

Добавь `values-v21` папку в RES и в нее `styles.xml` c кодом

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@style/Theme.Material.Light" >
```